# How to give the location of "Input" and "Output" for a python code using User Interface and run the code from UI itself?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a python code :

```
import gdal
import numpy
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
ds = gdal.Open('A:\\algo\\f2.tif')
```

In this code, line 4 gives the location/path of "input file" and line 10 gives the location of "output file".

I want to create a user interface to give this location in the user interface itself and run the code from user interface itself.

I have tried making a user interface using "tkinter" module :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
def input():
    file1 = filedialog.askopenfile()
    label = Label(text=file1).pack()
def input2():
    file2 = filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode="w", defaultextension=".tif")
    label = Label(text=file2).pack()    
w = Tk()
w.geometry("500x500")
w.title("FLOOD_MAPPER")
h = Label(text = "S1A FLOOD MAPPER", bg = "yellow", fg = "black", height = "3", width = "500")
h.pack()
i1 = Label(text = "Input*")
i1.place(x=10, y=70)
i1b = Button(w, text = "Select File", command =input)
i1b.place(x=250, y=70)
i2 = Label(text = "Intermediate Product*")
i2.place(x=10, y=140)
i2b = Button(w, text = "Save as", command =input2)
i2b.place(x=250, y=140)
button = Button(w, text="Generate Map", bg = "red", fg = "black", height = "2", width="30")
button.place(x=150, y=400)
w.mainloop()
```

But I didn't understand how to link these two codes.

The moment I click on button "generate map" in the user interface I want the location/path of Input and output given in the user interface box to move to their respective places in the 1st code and then run the same code aumoatically.

Kindly, help me to achieve my requirement.

Comment: put you code in function ie. `def my_code()` and assing to button `Button( command=my_code)`

Comment: @furas What will it do exactly, if I do so.

Comment: it will run your code when you press button.

Comment: @that's fine. What about passing the input and output location ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can look like this. I removed keep only important elements in tkinter.

I put code in `your_code` and it can get filenames as paramaters. So this code looks similar as before.

I create function `gen_map` which get run `your_code` with filenames which are assigned to global variables `input_filename`, `output_filename.

I assing `gen_map` to button `Button( command=gen_map)` so it will run it when you press button.

Other buttons open dialog to get file names and assign to global variables `input_filename`, `output_filename`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

import gdal
import numpy
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu

def your_code(input_file, output_file):

    #ds = gdal.Open('A:\\algo\\f2.tif')

    ds = gdal.Open(input_file)

    band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
    arr = band.ReadAsArray()
    thresh = threshold_otsu(arr,16)
    binary = arr > thresh
    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")

    #outdata = driver.Create("A:\\algo\\test11.tif", 14823, 9985, 1, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
    outdata = driver.Create(output_file, 14823, 9985, 1, gdal.GDT_UInt16)

    outdata.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
    outdata.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())
    outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(binary)
    outdata.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(10000)
    outdata.FlushCache() ##saves to disk!!

    #outdata = None
    #band = None
    #ds = None

def get_input_filename():
    global input_filename

    # `askopenfilename` instead of `askopenfile` to get filename instead of object file
    input_filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    input_label['text'] = input_filename

def get_output_filename():
    global output_filename

    # `asksaveasfilename` instead of `asksaveasfile` to get filename instead of object file
    output_filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".tif")
    output_label['text'] = output_filename

def gen_map():
    #global input_filename
    #global output_filename
    print('input:', input_filename)
    print('output:', output_filename)

    your_code(input_filename, output_filename)

#---------------------------------------------
# global variables with default values at start

input_filename = 'A:\\algo\\f2.tif'
output_filename = "A:\\algo\\test11.tif"

root = Tk()

#input_label = Label(root, text=input_filename)
input_label = Label(root, text="Input*")
input_label.pack()

input_button = Button(root, text="Select File", command=get_input_filename)
input_button.pack()

#output_label = Label(root, text=output_filename)
output_label = Label(root, text="Intermediate Product*")
output_label.pack()

output_button = Button(root, text="Save as", command=get_output_filename)
output_button.pack()

gen_map_button = Button(root, text="Generate Map", command=gen_map)
gen_map_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: can you explain me whats happening in def gen_map():

Comment: when you use dialogs to select files then tehy keep filenames in viarables `input_filename` and `output_filename`. `gen_map` gets filenames from `input_filename` and `output_filename` and runs function `you_code` with these filenames. And your code gets these filenames and use them to read and write data. `command=` expects function name without `()` and arguments so I can't assing `command= your_code(input_filename, output_filename)` - this is why I created `gen_map` to assign it as `command=gen_map`

Comment: encountered with following error : `Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "<ipython-input-4-675a3c59d479>", line 50, in gen_map
your_code(input_filename, output_filename)
File "<ipython-input-4-675a3c59d479>", line 21, in your_code
outdata = driver.Create(output_file, 14823, 9985, 1, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 1743, in Create
 return _gdal.Driver_Create(self, *args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: not a string`

Comment: I changed `asksaveasfile` into `asksaveasfilename` one hour ago - maybe you use old version. `asksaveasfilename` gives name of file, `asksaveasfile` was giving object file (result of `open(selected_filename)`). Your code need first one - `asksaveasfilename` - which give name of file, not file object.

Comment: can I include any status bar on UI window to show "processing" once, I click on "generate map" button and then "Processed" once it is completed(when output is generated).

Comment: you can add `Label` and change text in it. In current code I change text in `Label` to display selected filename. Tkitner has also [progressbar](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter/progressbar) but if you start long-running process then `mainloop` waits for its end and it can't update progressbar (and it also can't response for clicked buttons or update text in Label or status bar.)

Comment: I want to run another command from my python code and at the same time i want to give input_file to it by using UI. Original one - `import os
cmd = "gpt F:\saikiran\myGraph.xml -Psource=F:\saikiran\subset_Orb.dim -Ptarget=F:\saikiran\ck7.tif"
os.system(cmd)
ds = gdal.Open("F:\\saikiran\\ck7.tif")`
for the above code is this correct : `import os
def your_code(input_file, intermediate_file, output_file):
cmd = "gpt F:\saikiran\myGraph.xml -Psource=input_file -Ptarget=intermediate_file"
os.system(cmd)
ds = gdal.Open("intermediate file")`

Comment: if you have more question or new problem than create new question on new page - you will have more space to put code, error message and descrition. And code will be more readable.

Comment: As per your advice, I posted an other question with my error. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55845327/unable-to-pass-location-of-input-and-output-to-an-extenal-command-using-user-int)