# Unable to pass location of input and output to an extenal command using User-Interface in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am completely new to python.

I am trying to pass the location  of Input and output using User interface as shown in this particular discussion [1]:[How to give the location of "Input" and "Output" for a python code using User Interface and run the code from UI itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55785159/how-to-give-the-location-of-input-and-output-for-a-python-code-using-user-in)

But here, I am calling an external command and trying to run it from my python code by passing location of input and output as in the above mentioned case.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

import numpy as np
import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()
import os
def your_code(input_file, intermediate_file, output_file):

    cmd = "gpt F:\saikiran\myGraph.xml -Psource=input_file - Ptarget=intermediate_file"
    os.system(cmd)
    ds = gdal.Open(intermediate_file)
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
……………………………………………...
#gen_map_button.place(x=230, y=300)
gen_map_button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

But I encountered with this error :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\GUI-pywt.py", line 145, in gen_map
your_code(input_filename, intermediate_filename, output_filename)
  File "C:\Users\User\GUI-pywt.py", line 15, in your_code
ds = gdal.Open(intermediate_file)
  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\osgeo\gdal.py", line 3251, in Open
return _gdal.Open(*args)
RuntimeError: F:/saikiran/ddd: No such file or directory
```

What mistake did i do ?

Comment: do you have file/folder `F:/saikiran/ddd` on your disk ?

Comment: your `cmd` is not correct. To use concatenate string with values from variables `cmd = " ... -Psource=" + input_file + " - Ptarget=" + intermediate_file` or use string formatting `cmd = " ...-Psource={} - Ptarget={}".format(input_file, intermediate_file)` With Python 3.7 or 3.6 you can use f-string `cmd = f"... -Psource={input_file} - Ptarget={intermediate_file}"`

Comment: `F:/saikiran/ddd` I gave this for intermediate output. ie. i am saving the output as ddd in. `F:/saikiran` which already exist.  Later, i am calling the same file "ddd" as input in `ds = gdal.Open(intermediate_file)`. since it is already created in the above cmd.

Comment: it seems `gdal.Open(intermediate_file)` doesn't see this file. If you create it with `cmd = "gpt ..."` then it may not exists because `cmd` is not correct - it doesn't use value from variable `intermediate_file` but literaly word `"intermediate_file"` as filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `cmd` is not correct.

Concatenate string with values

```
cmd = "gpt F:\saikiran\myGraph.xml -Psource=" + input_file + " - Ptarget=" + intermediate_file
```

or use string formatting

```
cmd = "gpt F:\saikiran\myGraph.xml -Psource={} - Ptarget={}".format(input_file, intermediate_file)
```

With Python 3.6 or 3.7 you can use `f-string`

```
cmd = f"gpt F:\saikiran\myGraph.xml -Psource={input_file} - Ptarget={intermediate_file}"
```

---

Current `cmd`

```
"gpt F:\saikiran\myGraph.xml -Psource=input_file - Ptarget=intermediate_file"
```

will create file with name literally

```
 intermediate_file
```

not

```
 F:/saikiran/ddd
```

and it can make problem in `gdal.Open()`